# Spring boot , testing crud repository

Tags: java, testing, spring-boot

I never write tests for my rest controllers and services.
I have read offical docs , how to write integration tests in spring boot.
So for example I have a Rest Controller class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "users")
public class SvcUser {

    @RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> registrateUser(@RequestBody Registration registrate) throws TimeoutException, SocketTimeoutException  {

        final String result = userService.registrateUser(registrate.getPhoneCode(), registrate.getPhoneNumber(), registrate.getOsType());
        return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
    }
```

And inside userServiceClass i did smth like this

```
  registrateUser(String args ...){
         Users user = new User();
         user.setSmth(smth);
         userRepository.save(user)

   }
```

My integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,classes = GmoikaApiApplication.class)

    public class GmoikaApiApplicationTests {

        private MockMvc mockMvc;
        @Autowired
        private WebApplicationContext wac;
        @Before
        public void setUp(){
            this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
        }

        @Test
        public void firstTest() throws Exception {
            mockMvc.perform(post("/users/user")
                    .content("my new user"))
                    .andExpect(status().isOk())
                    .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.error",is(0)))
                    .andDo(print())
                    .andReturn();        
        }
```

And this is work fine, but i have new user in my db. I don't wanna create fake users in production only due to tests.My question is how to avoid creation of new users in db inside integration tests?

Comment: Use testing db that means `hsqldb` is default for spring testing. You may use it.

Comment: You can use `@Transactional` and `@Rollback` to create the user and then roll it back in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your project is a Maven project, then:

1. Add the following dependency to **pom.xml**

   `<dependency>
     <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
     <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
     <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>`
2. Add to **src/test/resources/config** the file **application.properties** containing something similar to:

   `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:mytestdb
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
   spring.datasource.username=sa
   spring.datasource.password=
   spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
   spring.jpa.database=H2
   spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
   spring.jpa.show-sql=false
   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop`

Comment: I also have application.properties file with my postgresql datasource, should i duplicate this file?

Comment: you **application.properties** is located in **src/main/resources** or **src/test/resources**?

Comment: sorry, i know that it should be the separate question, but i found that annotated my test class with @Transactional will roll back by bd after testing, is it better than use your approach?

Comment: my approach (which is not really my) is safer because it uses a separate database for tests

Answer (score 0):

You need to create profiles in spring framework, 1st for your standard  application with your database configuration and another for your test application, For testing you should use h2database. H2 database is in-memory databases so you don't need to any h2 database in installation, just add the dependency of h2database in project

com.h2database
    h2
    1.4.194

also in your test profile

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create
```